# routing error uninitialized constant API rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I have referred this [link](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2013/06/13/building-awesome-rails-apis-part-1/)

to create my own api but facing an routing error since this is the first time am using namespace.

This is the controller I have

```
class API::IndexController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @clients = Client.all
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json
    end
  end
end
```

my route has

```
  namespace :api do
    resources :index
  end
```

Here is my inflection.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
    inflect.acronym 'API'
end
```

Once i finish it I tried localhost:3000/api/index.json but throwing error as

```
    Routing Error
uninitialized constant API
```

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 10):

Even if this question is pretty old...

I had the same problem and my solution was to rename the api-folders (in app/controllers and app/views) from "API" (full caps) to "api" (all lower case)

Hope this helps

Comment: This wasn't my actual error, but it sure gave me the clue I needed to find it

Comment: Ran into a similar issue when using Travis-CI on my project. The tests worked fine with a namespace of `:api` and dir of `Api` but failed on the CI machine. I changed the dir name to `api` and all the tests ran as expected.

Answer (score 6):

You must have the same name in your class same as your namespace. Try this:

```
class Api::IndexController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @clients = Client.all
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json
    end
  end
end
```

**routes:**

```
  namespace :api do
    resources :index
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat old question, but my experience could still be useful.
I found my problem was because of a typo in the file name, I had a class named `ApiFooController` and the file was named `api_foo_contoller.rb` (notice the missing 'n' in the file name).
So it seems this error comes down to one general problem, and it's failig to correctly follow the naming conventions.

My guess is the controller was probably placed under `controller/` path instead of `controller/api` and also the namespace should've been `Api`, not `API` (Not sure if adding `API` as an `Acronym` does the trick, I've never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining your namespace for `IndexController` as `API` then in your `routes.rb` it should be written as

```
  namespace :a_p_i do
    resources :index
  end
```

Otherwise, if you want to use what you have written in your routes file then just change the namespace for `IndexController` form `API` to `Api` . For Ex : `Api::IndexController`

Comment: getting error `'Api/index' is not a supported controller name`

Comment: Showing error in mapper.rb line 239. I think mistake is in controller

Comment: I am not sure whether the name `Index` for your controller is causing the issue. Just try to change the name of your controller from `IndexController` to something else and in routes as well

Answer (score 0):

To solve this add the following file

```
#./spec/support/api/helper.rb

module ApiHelper
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Rails.application
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include ApiHelper, :type => :api
end
```

Then include it in `spec_helper.rb`

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

Read https://gist.github.com/alex-zige/5795358 for more info.